# feature engineering how to create a features in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

I have taxi dataset as follows:
Vendor_id               int64
1   tpep_pickup_datetime   datetime64[ns]
2   tpep_dropoff_datetime  datetime64[ns]
3   passenger_count        float64
4   trip_distance          float64
5   RatecodeID             float64
6   store_and_fwd_flag     object
7   PULocationID           int64
8   DOLocationID           int64
9   payment_type           int64
10  fare_amount            float64
11  extra                  float64
12  mta_tax                float64
13  tip_amount             float64
14  tolls_amount           float64
15  improvement_surcharge  float64
16  total_amount           float64
17  congestion_surcharge   float64
18  airport_fee            float64

If I want to find if the trip is in rush hour or not using feature engineering. How to do it in jupyter notebook.
The rush hour time is not given, maybe it can be assume that the rush hour from 8 am to 10 am.

Thank you so much

I'm very confused and unable to find the answer how to do this or create new features. Please help me what to do. I know it's part of machine learning and I think it's using sklearn to do it? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @Iskander14yo sorry stupid question, but is it neccesary to drop the "pickup_hour"? 

why is that?

will it disturb the analysis later if I don't drop it?

Thank you

Comment: Because it assumes the rush hour from 8 am to 10 am. If its 2 pm to 4 pm then the code will be

(df['pickup_hour'] >= 14) & (df['pickup_hour'] < 16)

is it like that?

Answer (score 0):

Relying on your reasoning that rush hour is from 8 to 10 and assuming you've loaded your dataset into a DataFrame called `df`:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Extract the hour from the pickup datetime
df['pickup_hour'] = df['tpep_pickup_datetime'].dt.hour

# Determine if the trip is during rush hour
df['is_rush_hour'] = (df['pickup_hour'] >= 8) & (df['pickup_hour'] < 10).astype(int)

# Drop the 'pickup_hour' column as it was just an intermediate step
df.drop(columns='pickup_hour', inplace=True)
```

The `is_rush_hour` column is now added to your DataFrame, where 1 indicates "Rush Hour" and 0 indicates "Not Rush Hour"

Answer (score 0):

use pandas for manipulation with your data, I think sklearn is not the right tool for your task

code below calculate 2 hours interval and find max as we consider as rush interval and then we define is_rush_hour column which is  boolean variable, row with true is a ride in rush hours

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('your_dataset.csv')
df['pickup_hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['tpep_pickup_datetime']).dt.hour

# 2 hours interval count the number of rides
df['pickup_hour_interval'] = pd.cut(df['pickup_hour'], bins=range(0, 25, 2))
hourly_counts = df.groupby('pickup_hour_interval').size().reset_index(name='ride_count')

# find the maximum count of rides 2-hour interval
max_rush_hour_interval = hourly_counts.iloc[hourly_counts['ride_count'].idxmax()]

print("2-Hour Rush Hour Interval with Maximum Rides:")
print(max_rush_hour_interval)

rush_hour_start = max_rush_hour_interval['pickup_hour_interval'].left
rush_hour_end = max_rush_hour_interval['pickup_hour_interval'].right
df['is_rush_hour'] = df['pickup_hour'].between(rush_hour_start, rush_hour_end)
```